# Estimate missing coordinates in a trajectory of points in Python

Tags: python, gdal, point, gps

I have points with longitude, latitude and date, being the trajectory of a boat taken every day.
One point is missing and I have to estimate it with Python.

Is there built-in libraries doing that or should I only consider that:

- boat is going at constant speed that I compute from other points
- boat is keeping the same direction

and compute the point from that ?

--edit--

To have a good estimate I would like to be sure that the estimated point is not on the ground.

Comment: isn't that a simple averaging problem?

Comment: It is indeed but being a boat, two points separated by ground, I would have a better estimate by finding a point on the sea. I was wondering if some more robust libraries than only averaging have been developed. I will clarify my question.